# Form with custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a form in my app that exists out of a `UITableView` with custom cells. These cells can contain a `UITextField`, `UISegmentedControl` or a `UISwitch`. This is how I set this up:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewInner cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DetailTableViewCell *cell;

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    DetailTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[DetailTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setTextField:@"John Appleseed"];

    // or 

    [cell setSegment];
    [cell setSegmentIndex:1];

    // or

    [cell setSwitch];
    [cell setSwitchEnabled:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

Now, when a user taps the save button I need to fetch all this information and `init` a model with it, like this:

```
[[Restaurant alloc] initWithName:@"Name here" withNotifications:1 withFrequency:1 withDate:@"Date here" andWithDistance:@"Distance here"];
```

What's the best and cleanest way possible to convert all these inputs to data in my model? I feel like looping over all the cells is a bit over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> like looping over all the cells is a bit over the top

It isn't just over the top: it's totally wrong. The data doesn't live in the cells; it lives in the data. Model, view, controller; the cell is just *view*! Its job is to *represent* the model (the data). There should be nothing to loop over, therefore; you should already have the data as data.

> Now, when a user taps the save button I need to fetch all this information

Actually, what I would do is capture the information when the user makes the change. Give the text field, switch, or segmented control a control action-target so that a message is sent to you telling you that something happened (e.g. the switch value changed, the text was edited, and so on) and capture the data right then.

The only question then becomes: I've received a message from a control: what row of the table is it in? To find out, walk the hierarchy up from the control until you come to the cell, and then ask the table what row this cell represents:

```
UIView* v = sender; // the control
do {
    v = v.superview;
} while (![v isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]);
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)v;
NSIndexPath* ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: Actual code example in this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_editable_content_in_table_items

Comment: I have to say also: I don't like the Save architecture very much. Users don't expect to have to tap Save to make their changes stick. They expect their changes to be saved automatically as they make them. That is how my book example behaves.

Answer (score 0):

A more cleaner approach using custom blocks.
**DetailTableViewCell.h**

```
typedef void (^ saveBlock_block_t )(WhateverYourReturnObjectType *obj);

@interface DetailTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)configureCell:(NSString *)textFieldVal
               cellBlock:(saveBlock_block_t)cellBlock;
@end
```

**DetailTableViewCell.m**

```
@interface DetailTableViewCell ()
{
  @property (copy, nonatomic) saveBlock_block_t saveBlock;
}
@end

@implementation DetailTableViewCell

- (void)configureCell:(NSString *)textFieldVal
               cellBlock:(saveBlock_block_t)cellBlock
{
  [cell setTextField: textFieldVal];
  [self setSaveBlock:cellBlock];
}

-(IBAction)saveButtonAction:(id)sender  //Action on your save button
{
 self.cellBlock(obj); // Whatever object you want to return to class having your table object
}
@end
```

Then from cellForRowAtIndexPath call it as -

```
[cell configureCell:@"John Appleseed”
      cellBlock:^(WhateverYourReturnObjectType *obj){

       //Do what you want to do with 'obj' which is returned by block instance in the cell
 }];
```